# How to communicate between ionic (cordova) application and arduino

Tags: cordova, arduino, ionic-framework, iot

I want to develop and ionic application to switch ON and OFF LEDs attached with arduino. How will I communicate between arduino and cordova application??

Comment: The question is incomplete. How do you want to communicate with the Arduino? Ethernet? Wifi? Bluetooth? NFC? (if I can choose I prefer via Ethernet)

Comment: I want to communicate with Ethenet or Wifi... wifi is my priority...

Answer (score 1):

Bluetooth is one of the most popular protocols for wireless communication between devices. Bluetooth powers a countless number of devices, from Bluetooth speakers, to smartwatches, headsets, fitness trackers, and more.

[Tutorial](http://iotdesign.embedded-computing.com/articles/build-an-internet-connected-bluetooth-wearable-with-arduino-and-cordova-part-one/) will walk you through how you can create your own Bluetooth fitness tracker using **Arduino and Cordova**. This tutorial will be talking to your Arduino over Bluetooth.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use TCP/IP communication (Ethernet / Wifi / etc.) you could create a sketch on the Arduino that listen incoming connection, here is a small example: [EthernetServer](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/EthernetServer) - and when a client connects you control the outputs with the usual functions (pinMode / digitalWrite).

Then with Ionic (Angular to be precise) you can use the [$http](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) functions or [ngResource](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource) (if you like the resource-way) to make GET requests to the Arduino IP (setup a static one, to keep it simple).

And if you want to expand the system to something more complex you could use the Arduino Yun for example. It has an internal webserver already setup, used for the Arduino config. For a project I moved the internal CGI files (that serve the config interface) to offer my own interface.

Comment: So friend, in ionic I can send a comand to Arduino or Espe32, for exemplo I have a button then in click we have the following code : click -> h ttp://192.0.0.0/12, its ok?